# How to save file in Temporary Internet Files

Tags: c#, wpf, console-application, temporary-files

I want create cache some files `.js` after windows initialization with my console application, but i'm not able.

My code:

```
var tempFilePath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.InternetCache);
var filePath = Path.Combine(tempFilePath,"My.js");

var requestFile = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("http://my-address/My.js");
requestFile.Method = "GET";

var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)(requestFile.GetResponse());

using (var responseStream = httpResponse.GetResponseStream())
{
    var myJS = new StreamReader(responseStream).ReadToEnd();

    File.WriteAllText(filePath, myJS);
}
```

Comment: what does "not able" mean?

Comment: This code run success, but file not appear.

Comment: What makes you think that creating a random file in that directory will make browsers use that file as cache when trying to access a file with the same name on some random server? If it was that simple, no website could ever cache a `index.html`.

Comment: Right. It's possible create a cache script with c#?

Comment: No. A browser’s cache handling is completely up to the browser and also different for every browser, so it’s very unlikely that you can affect that.

Comment: OK, thanks so much for your help, you think in another solution for download some .js and save in cache, before user enter in the determined site?

Comment: Why do you want to do that in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, in order to write files directly to the IE cache folder, you'll need to use wininet.dll

You can use the `CreateUrlCacheEntry` and `CommitUrlCacheEntryW` functions to inject files into the cache.

[Reference 1.](http://887%20affaires%20de%20disparition%20d%E2%80%99enfants%20en%202017%20en%20Alg%C3%A9rie)

[Reference 2.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235282.aspx)